# How to include jar files in Netbeans from environment variable?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-6.9

This might be a beginners question but I couldn't find a way to do it at all.

I want to include some libraries to my Netbeans project from an environment variable. I am trying to include library files from AXIS_HOME/lib/ folder which can be anywhere on the system. Is there a way to do it from within the project?

** **Note:** AXIS_HOME is an environment variable defined at:

> > MyComputer -> Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> System Variables